is it "she has been right the whole time" or " she was right the whole time"?
I want to know what to use if I were to imply that what someone used to say has always been right and correct, even though we never accepted it.

the whole time normally refers to some specific span of time. In your case you've already used the correct adverb: She has always been right. You'd normally only use She has been right all the time... if immediately followed by, say, ...so far (which at least places an upper limit on the time-period over which she's been right).

I sincerely appreciate your insights. Thank you for sharing your perspective.

Since you say "what someone used to say has always been right" (my emphasis on the fact that she no longer says it):
She was right all along.
She was right the entire time.
If she is still saying it, insisting that it's right despite opposition or even though people have never accepted what she has been saying, change "was" to "has been".

She was the Miss Right at all times.

@gomadeng "at all times" is a different kind of "always" :  on every occasion, in every situation.
